# Connection the ROS/ROS2 and MoveIt to ABB4600

Tags: ros, ros2, abb

I want to connect ROS and ROS2 + MoveIt to our ABB IRB4600 robot for a real-time control and path planning. I have two questions:

1. I am going over this page and it looks like we upload the ROS code as a rapid code on the FlexPendant, so it is not real-time. Please let me know if I'm wrong: https://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver/Tutorials/RunServer
2. These drivers are for ROS and ROS2 only has ABB IRB1200. Is it possible to change it for ABB IRb4600?

I would appreciate your guidance on how I connect our ABB IRB4600 with IRC5 controller to ROS/ROS2 and MoveIt for a real-time control and planning.